# A question in proof of a theorem in Structure of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

While studying Abstract algebra from Thomas Hungerford I am struck at a step in proof on page 109-110 of textbook.

I am adding it's image as writing whole proof will take a lot of time.

Image:[image]

In the red highlighted line $ac$ belongs to ${\rm Ker} f$ implies $Dc= D$ but how does it implies $c=a_{1}c_{1}$, with... .

I am unable to prove this step despite a lot of manipulation.

So, can anyone please tell how can I prove it.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$ac \in \ker f \iff c \in D$ comes from the definition of $f$ at the beginning of the paragraph.

Since $D = (A^* \cap B)(A \cap B^*)$ by definition, $c \in D$ means there exists $a_1 \in A^* \cap B$ and $c_1 \in A \cap B^*$ such that $c = a_1 c_1$.

---

Edit: $f$ is a homomorphism to the quotient group $(A \cap B)/D$ whose identity element is the coset $D$. Thus the kernel of $f$ consists of elements of $A^*(A \cap B)$ that map to $D$. Since $f$ is defined as $f(ac)=Dc$ for $a \in A^*$ and $c \in A \cap B$, we want $Dc=D$, i.e. $c \in D$.

Comment: can you please tell how can it be deduced that  ac$\in$ kerf iff c $\in $ D?

Comment: @Tim See my edit